# Why proxPN cannot connect on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, vpn

I am located in China and just installed proxPN on my MacBook. But it does not connect to the server in Dallas, it always hangs there.
What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Please contact us directly at support@proxpn.com

Answer (score 1):

Many people in China experience the open vpn protocol being blocked. The only way around this would be to use the PPTP protocol which is available with a premium account.

Comment: I concur. I use ProXPN in China and this is the only way to connect... using PPTP.